# Ember: Get the value of textarea from route

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I want to get the value of the textarea to use inside my route.  I tried using the method below, but the alert shows 'undefined' for that value.  How would I go about getting the value of the textarea from the route? I am running the latest version of ember-cli.

**Template**

```
{{textarea type="text" value='name'}}
<button {{action 'submit'}} >Send</button>
```

**Route**

```
actions: {
    submit: function() { alert(this.get('name'));
    }   }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to pass a variable through action `submit`, which is bound to textarea `value`. Usually such a variable is defined in controller (or in wrapper component).

```
//template
{{textarea type="text" value=name}}
<button {{action 'submit' name}} >Send</button>

//controller
name: 'defaultName'

//route
actions: {
  submit: function(val) { 
    alert(val);
  }
}
```

[Working jsbin here](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/lowecadibo/1/edit?html,js,output)